# Prove quotient of two $N(0,1)$ is $\text{Cauchy}(0,1)$

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions

Problem: Show that if $X$ and $Y$ are independent $N(0,1)$-distributed random variables, then $X/Y ∈ C(0,1)$.

Question: I don't know how to proceed below. I want to prove that the PDF of $X/Y$ is Cauchy. PS. I looked on wiki and they *defined* $C$ as $X/Y$

Attempt: [image]

The expression looked hairy and [wolfram](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate+1%2Fpi%5E2*1%2F%281%2Bw%5E2v%5E2%29*1%2F%281%2Bw%5E2%29*abs%28v%29+dv+from+-infty+to+infty) could not integrate it.

Note to self: problem 8.

Comment: Ain't $f_X$ and $f_Y$ p.d.fs of normal distribution? Why have you substituted the Cauchy p.d.f formula?

Comment: forgot to link to exercise http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/917912/derive-the-density-for-the-difference-and-ratio-respectively-of-two-independen

Comment: http://www.math.wm.edu/~leemis/chart/UDR/PDFs/StandardnormalStandardcauchy.pdf

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $Z=X/Y$.
Then
$$
Ef(Z) = \int f(x/y)n(x)n(y) dxdy
= \int f(z) n(yz)n(y)|y|dydz
$$
With $n(x) = \frac1{\sqrt{2\pi}} \exp(-x^2/2)$
and $\sigma(z)^2 = 1/(1+z^2)$,
$$
n(y)n(yz) = \frac1{2\pi} \exp((1+z^2)(-y^2/2))
= \frac 1{2\pi} \exp(-y^2/2\sigma(z)^2)
\\
\int n(yz)n(y)|y|dy
=  2\int_0^\infty \frac 1{2\pi} \exp(-y^2/2\sigma(z)^2)ydy\\
= \frac{\sigma(z)^2}{\pi} \int_0^\infty \exp(-y^2/2\sigma(z)^2)\frac{y}{\sigma(z)}
\frac{dy}{\sigma(z)} = \frac{\sigma(z)^2}{\pi}
\\
Ef(Z) = \int f(z) n(yz)n(y)|y|dydz
= \int f(z)  \frac{\sigma(z)^2}{\pi} dz
= \int f(z)  \frac{dz}{\pi(1+z^2)} 
$$

Comment: Did you really need the last line $Ef(Z) = ...$ ? Since you derived the correct PDF shouldn't the proof be done then?

Comment: In the last step, when you conclude $= \frac{\sigma(z)^2}{\pi}$ did you recognize it as an exponential PDF summing to 1?

Comment: @jacob the derivative of $\exp(g(x))$ is $g'(x) \exp(g(x))$

Comment: the method with the computation of $Ef(Z)$ is general.

Comment: what do you want to say regarding the derivative? Don't understand how that answers my comment.

Comment: $\int_0^\infty \exp(-y^2/2\sigma(z)^2)\frac{y}{\sigma(z)}
\frac{dy}{\sigma(z)} = \int_0^\infty \exp(-u^2/2)u du =\left[                                 -\exp(-u^2/2)                             \right]_0^\infty = 1$

Comment: thanks. and what do you mean with "general", I can't see how we loose generality by concentrating on proving the PDF is the same.

Comment: pdf may not exist.

Answer (score 3):

An alternative proof taken from [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xiVWNkQUqKk&list=PL2SOU6wwxB0uwwH80KTQ6ht66KWxbzTIo&index=20) - I find it helpful as most steps are explained intuitively. Please correct me if something is incorrect.

#### Proof

Start with the CDF which is $P(\frac{X}{Y} \leq t)$ which is an event, and we want to find the probability of this event.

$$ P(\frac{X}{Y} \leq t)  = P(\frac{X}{|Y|} \leq t) = P(X \leq |Y|t) \text{  by symmetry of } N(0,1) $$

To get a probability, integrate the joint pdf over the region of interest. For $Y$ this is between $- \infty$ to $\infty$ but for $X$ this is from $- \infty$ to $t |y|$ !

$$P(X \leq |Y|t)  = \int_{- \infty}^{\infty} \int_{- \infty}^{t |y|} f(x,y) \ dx \ dy $$

As $X$ and $Y$ are i.i.d. the joint PDF can be found by multiplying the pdf : $f_{X,Y}(x,y) = f_X(x) f_Y(y)$

\begin{aligned}
 P(X \leq |Y|t)  &= \int_{- \infty}^{\infty} \int_{- \infty}^{t |y|} \frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi}} \frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi}} e^{- \frac{1}{2}(x^2 + y^2)}\ dx \ dy 
 \\
 & = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi}} \int_{- \infty}^{\infty}  e^{- \frac{1}{2} y^2} \int_{- \infty}^{t |y|}  \frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi}} e^{- \frac{1}{2} x^2}\ dx \ dy 
\end{aligned}

Recognize that the inner integral cannot be computed analytically, however this is the normal CDF $\Phi(t |y|)$

\begin{aligned}
 P(X \leq |Y|t)   & = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi}} \int_{- \infty}^{\infty}  e^{- \frac{1}{2} y^2} \Phi(t |y|) \ dy 
\end{aligned}

This is an even function so we can remove the absolute value and multiply by 2.

\begin{aligned}
 P(X \leq |Y|t)   & = \frac{2}{\sqrt{2 \pi}} \int_{0}^{\infty}  e^{- \frac{1}{2} y^2} \Phi(t y) \ dy 
\end{aligned}

The PDF is the derivative of the CDF, so we can take the derivative of the above equation. Under mild technical conditions we can swap the derivative and the integral. Note that $y$ is a dummy variable so here we need to take the derivative w.r.t. $t$

\begin{aligned}
 PDF = F'(t) & = \frac{d}{dt}  \frac{2}{\sqrt{2 \pi}} \int_{0}^{\infty} e^{- \frac{1}{2} y^2} \Phi(t y) \ dy 
 \\
  & = \frac{2}{\sqrt{2 \pi}} \int_{0}^{\infty} e^{- \frac{1}{2} y^2} \ \frac{d}{dt} \Phi(t y) \ dy 
\end{aligned}

To compute the derivative use the chain rule:  $\frac{d}{dt} \Phi(t y) = \frac{d \Phi(t y) }{d(ty)} \frac{d (t y) }{d(t)} = y \frac{d \Phi(t y) }{d(ty)} = y \phi(ty)$ where $\phi(ty)$ is the normal pdf of $(ty)$

\begin{aligned}
 F'(t) & = \sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi}} \int_{0}^{\infty}  y \ e^{- \frac{1}{2} y^2} \  \phi(t y) \ dy 
 \\
 & = \sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi}} \int_{0}^{\infty} y \  e^{- \frac{1}{2} y^2} \frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi}} e^{- \frac{t^2y^2 }{2}} \ dy 
 \\
 & = \frac{1}{\pi} \int_{0}^{\infty} y e^{ - \frac{1}{2}(1 + t^2)y^2 } dy
\end{aligned}

Which can be solved using substitution $u = \frac{1}{2}(1 + t^2)y^2$ so $du = y (1 + t^2) dy$

\begin{aligned}
 F'(t) & =  \frac{1}{\pi} \int_{0}^{\infty} y e^{ - \frac{1}{2}(1 + t^2)y^2 } dy
 \\
 & =  \frac{1}{\pi(1 + t^2)} \int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-u}  \ du
 \\
 & =  \frac{1}{\pi(1 + t^2)}  \ \ \forall t
\end{aligned}

#### Additional detail about the symmetry of $N(0,1)$ - Taken from [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2190509/cauchy-cdf-derivation-from-standard-normal)

The probability $P( X/Y\leqslant t)$ may be viewed as
\begin{aligned}
&P(\lbrace X/Y\leqslant t, Y>0 \rbrace\cup\lbrace X/Y\leqslant t, Y<0 \rbrace) \\
=\; &P(X/|Y|\leqslant t, Y>0) + P(-X/|Y|\leqslant t, Y<0)\\
=\; &P(X/|Y|\leqslant t, Y>0) + P(X/|Y|\leqslant t, Y<0)\\
=\; &P(X/|Y|\leqslant t)
\end{aligned}
by symmetry of the standard normal distribution, independence and the fact that $P(Y=0)=0$.

Comment: See [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2190509/418542) for intermediate details

Comment: Great thanks ! I was also uncertain about the symmetry part. Will edit my post to add the intuition.