# Derive cdf of Cauchy distribution from standard normal distribution

Tags: statistics, random-variables, normal-distribution, cumulative-distribution-functions

This [post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2190509/cauchy-cdf-derivation-from-standard-normal#) is about the process to calculate the **cdf** of Cauchy distribution from $X, Y \overset{i.i.d} \sim N(0, 1)$

\begin{aligned}
&P(\lbrace X/Y\leqslant t, Y>0 \rbrace\cup\lbrace X/Y\leqslant t, Y<0 \rbrace) \\
=\; &P(X/|Y|\leqslant t, Y>0) + P(-X/|Y|\leqslant t, Y<0) \quad \\
=\; &P(X/|Y|\leqslant t, Y>0) + P(X/|Y|\leqslant t, Y<0)\\
=\; &P(X/|Y|\leqslant t)
\end{aligned}

But I still have a problem to understand why
$P(\lbrace X/Y\leqslant t, Y>0 \rbrace\cup\lbrace X/Y\leqslant t, Y<0 \rbrace)$ is equivalent to $P(X/|Y|\leqslant t, Y>0) + P(-X/|Y|\leqslant t, Y<0)$

First, why is it valid to covert $Y$ to $\mid Y \mid$? It seems that it is related to the symmetry of the normal distribution, but I failed to make a mathematical proof.

Second, the reason $X$ is converted to $-X$ in second line is both $X$ and $-X$ are same distribution with $N(0, 1)$?

Please give me some detailed and answer. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$
Z:=\frac{X}{Y}1\{Y\ne 0\}=\frac{X}{|Y|}1\{Y>0\}-\frac{X}{|Y|}1\{Y<0\}+0\cdot\{Y=0\}.
$$
Since the sets $\{Y>0\}$, $\{Y<0\}$, and $\{Y=0\}$ are disjoint,
\begin{align}
\mathsf{P}(Z\le t)&=\mathsf{P}(\{Z\le t\}\cap \{Y>0\}) \\
&\quad+\mathsf{P}(\{Z\le t\}\cap \{Y<0\}) \\
&\quad+\mathsf{P}(\{Z\le t\}\cap \{Y=0\}) \\
&=\ldots
\end{align}
Note that $Z=X/|Y|$ on $\{Y<0\}$, $Z=-X/|Y|$ on $\{Y<0\}$, and $\{Y=0\}$ is a null set.

Comment: You saved me, Thanks!